# How to allow only https in the ios app using ATS?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I have multiple of subdomains for which I allow http and https requests. Now I want only HTTP request to be allowed for all the domains/subdomains.

```
I tried setting ATS as false but it didn't work. Do we need to do other configurations?<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <false/>
</dict>
```

Comment: You can just remove all of the ats keys. The default behaviour is to permit https only.

Comment: @ashwini the question and the explanation are contradictory, do you make only http or https call from the app now?